# How to get all file name from zip folder using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip

I want to get all file name from a zip folder and save into database. please give me suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

> its very simple just use ZipArchive

```
$zip = new ZipArchive; 
if ($zip->open('logs.zip')) 
{ 
     for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) 
     {   
          echo 'Filename: ' . $zip->getNameIndex($i) . '<br />'; 
     } 
} 
else 
{ 
     echo 'Error reading zip-archive!'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$path = 'zipfile.zip'

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($path) === true) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $filename = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
        $fileinfo = pathinfo($filename);
        copy("zip://".$path."#".$filename, "/your/new/destination/".$fileinfo['basename']);
    }                   
    $zip->close();                   
}

?>
```